Why IDEA underscores a variable inside lambda-expression as if it is reassigned, though it is used just to return a value?
Given instance method
void f() {
    int var = 6;   

    Function<Integer, Integer> myFunc = (x) -> {return var; };
  }

var is underlined (only once - inside lambda).
Usually, if I really reassign (say writevar = 7after var = 6) - both occurrences of var are underlined.
But in my case only occurrence inside lambda is underlined.
Could you please provide any comments concerning such IDE behavior?
I expected that there is no reassignment here and so var would not be underlined at all!

The underlining is an indication that you're using a variable that's defined outside of the lambda. In the settings it's found under "implicit anonymous class parameter". That's not quite what it is, but that's kind of the "predecessor" of what using effective final variables used in a lambda is.

